# Java Throw NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception, if-statement, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I'm suppose to catch the NoSuchElementException if a field is missing while reading a file. If there is a field missing, I just need to skip to the next line of the file. My question is, where do I implement my try/catch code to do this? Here is the codes:

```
String petType;
int lineNumber = 0;

while(input.hasNext()) {

  petType = input.next();
  lineNumber++;

  //I'm thinking of doing it for every if(input.hasNext()) but that would be too messy to read.
  if(petType.equals("BIRD")) {
    if(input.hasNext())
      String name = input.next();
    if(input.hasNext())
      String owner = input.next();
    if(input.hasNextDouble())
      double weight = input.nextDouble();
    if(input.hasNextBoolean())
      boolean clipped = input.nextBoolean();
    Bird x = new Bird(name,owner,weight,clipped);
    object.addPet(x);
  }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that name is missing but owner is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of all your *hasNextXXX()* calls and let *nextXXX()* throw the exception for you.

```
String petType;
int lineNumber = 0;

while (input.hasNext()) {
    lineNumber++;    
    try {
        petType = input.next();
        if (petType.equals("BIRD")) {
            String name = input.next();
            String owner = input.next();
            double weight = input.nextDouble();
            boolean clipped = input.nextBoolean();
            Bird x = new Bird(name, owner, weight, clipped);
            object.addPet(x);
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
        System.out.println("something is missing in line " + lineNumber);
    }
}
```

That being said, I'd argue that it's better to keep all your hasNextXXX calls and to break out of the current iteration (using *continue*) if any of them return false.  This will achieve the same affect as catching the exception, but without the unneccessary overhead of using a try/catch.

My guess is your teacher just wants you to learn about Exceptions, though...

Answer (score 0):

If a field is missing - your input.hasNext()/input.hasNextDouble/input.hasNextBoolean will return false... Do you really need to catch an exception - since you are checking field existence anyway?

You can just skip to next line if any of the if conditions fail.